# Accessing resolved promise object properties

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I'm having trouble accessing resolved promise object properties.

Using fetch, I have a `.then` doing this:

`.then((response) => console.log(response.json()))`

I'm trying to access the `user` property of the response object by doing this:

`.then((response) => console.log(response.json().user))`

and it's returning `undefined`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

`response.json()` returns another Promise. You'll need to use another `.then()` callback:

```
fetch(...)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.user))
```